# Play HTML files from within SharePoint 2019 On-Prem?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have Learning and Development files saved in our SharePoint 2019 On-Prem site.  Is it possible to launch/play the HTML version in SharePoint 2019?  We can currently do that in our SharePoint 2010 On-Prem site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint on-premises, we can set Browser File Handling to Permissive for users to open html files directly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing but renamed the .html file to .aspx and placed it in the siteassets folder. This way you don't have to change Browser File Handling to Permissive. I tried adding some css and js files in my files and that also works.